# jQuery toggle nested ul from a link in parent li

Tags: jquery

This should be simple, but I can't get it to work when the 'trigger' is an anchor inside the li. I want the anchor, when clicked to toggle the appropriate nested ul. 
Here is the HTML:

```
<ul id="specs">
    <li>top level li</li>
    <li>top level li</li>
    <li>li to trigger nested list <a class="trigger" href="firstTrigger">first trigger</a> or <a class="trigger" href="secondTrigger">second trigger</a>.
        <ul id="hiddenList1">
            <li class="title">Title 1</li>
            <li>something</li>
            <li>something</li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="hiddenList2">
            <li class="title">Title 2</li>
            <li>something</li>
            <li>something</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to do it so I don't have to write a function for reach, to make it more global. Here is what I've tried but I come up with it either not working or adding the # to the url

```
$(function() {
    $('.trigger').click(function() {
        $(this).attr('href').toggle(slow);
        return false;
    )};
});
```

thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Save yourself a WHOLE lot of time.....just use Superfish.

Comment: @bpeterson - interesting...I use that for navigation drop downs but hadn't thought to use it here....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an attempted fix:

```
<ul id="specs">
    <li>top level li</li>
    <li>top level li</li>
    <li>li to trigger nested list <a class="trigger" href="firstTrigger">first trigger</a> or <a class="trigger" href="secondTrigger">second trigger</a>.
        <ul id="firstTrigger">
            <li class="title">Title 1</li>
            <li>something</li>
            <li>something</li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="secondTrigger">
            <li class="title">Title 2</li>
            <li>something</li>
            <li>something</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

$(function() {
    $('.trigger').click(function() {
        $("'#" + $(this).attr('href')).toggle('slow');
        return false;
    )};
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kcq7K/2/

Slightly modified version that doesn't rely on ids rather position:

```
$('.trigger').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('ul').eq($(this).index()).toggle('slow');
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kcq7K/3/

Comment: works exactly as I asked for it to with the addition of ul li ul {display:none;} how do I get them to work so only one is visible? that is if you trigger the first list, then click the second trigger it would slide the first up as the second slides in? kind of accordion like?

Comment: That's bit tricky but to give you an idea, see this: http://jsfiddle.net/kcq7K/5/

Comment: excellent, thank you. I actually understand what you coded, just couldn't come up with it by myself. thx again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

*HTML:*

```
<ul id="specs">
    <li>top level li</li>
    <li>top level li</li>
    <li>li to trigger nested list <a class="trigger" href="hiddenList1">first trigger</a> or <a class="trigger" href="hiddenList2">second trigger</a>.
        <ul id="hiddenList1">
            <li class="title">Title 1</li>
            <li>something</li>
            <li>something</li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="hiddenList2">
            <li class="title">Title 2</li>
            <li>something</li>
            <li>something</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
$(function() {
    $('.trigger').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#' + id).toggle('slow');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: toggle(slow) should be toggle('slow'), `)};` should be `});`,

Comment: No big deal - I make mistakes like that all the time. BTW, I'm not stalking you :).

Comment: I guess we're just both on the jQuery questions today.

Comment: @Matt - so I have it working, and thanks you answered exactly what I asked, but I omitted something. Is it possible to make one close when the other opens, so there is only one being displayed at a time?